# Variable page height with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: webkit, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to print various receipts using wkhtmltopdf (using the webkit reporting tool in openERP).

I have a receipt printer that has a continuous roll of paper. The printer automatically cuts the paper on a page break. This works great on receipts where the height of the "page" is always the same, but I can't figure out how to set the height dynamically on individual pages.

Ideally I want to put a `page-break-after:always` css command after every receipt and for wkhtmltopdf to set the height of the page to match the height of the content.

I'm guessing the only way is to hack the source code on https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf but hoping someone has already solved this problem.

Comment: Not sure if I am clear but wouldn't you just put this css into your report template so the css is in the HTML before it gets passed through to wkhtml2pdf to convert into a PDF?

Comment: yes i can put the css into the html but that forces a page break, it doesnt change the size of the page which is what I want to do. I think I should draw a picture :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at: https://github.com/AAverin/JSUtils/tree/master/wkhtmltopdfTableSplitHack

From what I understand, you would only need to define a specific class to your HTML table element, and the JS script would do the rest.

Also, you might want to look at theses (which eventually lead me to the first link)

- https://gist.github.com/niflostancu/3683510
- https://gist.github.com/bluntelk/5573089